# Ember Adapter API Method Name

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do I uppercase an api method?

I've got a model patient, and when it calls the server it's looking at server/patient and I need it to look at server/Patient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override buildUrl (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL) in your adapter.